# How can I update the Name of a Petrel Window?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I am trying to update the Name/Display Name of a Petrel Window after the Save event.

I implemented my own NameInfo class that inherits from the NameInfo abstract class.

```
 public class MyNameInfo : NameInfo
    {
        private string name = string.Empty;
        private string displayName = string.Empty;
        private string typeName = string.Empty;

        public override bool CanChangeName
        {
             get { return true; } //I return true so I can change the name at runtime.
        }
        //Rest of the class implementation
     }
```

My DisplayName, Name and TypeName has to be the same, so when the name is changed my code is:

```
public override string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                displayName = value;
                typeName = value;
                OnNameChanged(this);
            }
        }
```

I change the name of my window on the "Saved" event of the DataSourceManager:

```
DataManager.DataSourceManager.Saved += OnSave;
```

The code I use to update the name is:

```
if(NameInfo.CanChangeName)
     NameInfo.Name = NewName;
```

But when I change the name, it appears updated only in the tree of the **Windows** window.

The Name of my window shows the old name.

I dont know what else I have to do to achieve what I want.

My Window is a custom window

```
public class MyCustomWindow : ToggleWindow, INameInfoSource, IDeletable 
{
```

Is there a way to update the Window Name itself?

Do I have to subscribe my "MyCustomWindow" to some event and I am not doing it?

I will really appreciate any help you can offer me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you create your NameInfo in your custom window? You need to pass the custom window object to MyNameInfo such that you can call OnNameChanged(window) on the custom window object. Here's an example:

```
private MyNameInfo nameInfo = null;
public NameInfo NameInfo
{
  get
  {
    if (null == nameInfo)
    {
      nameInfo = new MyNameInfo(this);
    }
    return nameInfo;
  }
}
```

And then in your setter of the Name property of MyNameInfo,

```
set
{
   name = value;
   displayName = value;
   typeName = value;
   OnNameChanged(this.window);
}
```